# WildFly deploy fails

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, wildfly

I have been trying to work with WildFly, however I'm facing some odd issues, for example I can deploy from a *.war withouth any problem with connection to the database, but an unmanaged deployment is a headache, never starts, same when trying to do this throught Eclipse.

I'm doing a normal deploy for debugg using Eclipse, but anytime I'm getting this message:

**WFLYEE0027: Could not load oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver referenced in env-entry**.

I have all the runtime configuration in Eclipse and also I did all the module configuration inside WildFly for standalone. I have added the *.jar to the proyect manually.

[image: Java Build Path]

This is a maven project, any idea of how to solve this?

Comment: Lots of tutorials on configuring wildfly datasources. https://tomylab.wordpress.com/2016/07/24/how-to-add-a-datasource-to-wildfly/

Comment: @KarlNicholas that was not the problem, but thank you for the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, for this time I could solve the problem by adding the *.jar files this way:

[image: Configuration]

So now WildFly can load the libraries from the lib folder